# Execute query by selecting item from listbox in php

Tags: php, mysql, listbox, dropdownbox

- I want to select a item from listbox (say listbox 1) and just after
  selecting
- I want another list box (listbox 2) get data with the help
  of item selected in listbox 1.

List box 1 data:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">AXC-202</option>
  <option value="2">AXC-204</option>
  <option value="3">AXC-206</option>
  <option value="4">AXC-206</option>
</select>
```

Suppose if AXC-202 selected then listbox fill by query

```
$query = mysql_query("select from stats where sub = 1");//AXC-202

echo '<select name="Year">'; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['year'].'">'.$row['year'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

All this I wants to be done on single page.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: you need JS/Ajax to do this